# Screen out values which didn't fit two conditions

Tags: vba, excel

i wanna write a VBA programme that screen out values which didnt satisfy the specified values. However, I kinda stuck in the object-defined error of line 4 (If...Then). Would somebody pls help me out. Many thanks!!!!!!!!

```
Sub Macro1()
If Cells(A, 1) <> "none" Or Cells(A, 1) <> 0 Then
    Cells(A, 2) = "checked"
Else
    Cells(A, 2) = "Not checked"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your rows and columns reversed.  Try:

```
Sub Macro1()
If Cells(1, "A") <> "none" Or Cells(1, "A") <> 0 Then
    Cells(2, "A") = "checked"
Else
    Cells(2, "A") = "Not checked"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: but even when I corrected this one, the cells (2,"A") always display checked even when i input 1 in cells (1,"A") and run the program. Is there's something wrong with my statement?

Comment: What do you want to happen?  Now your statement says that anything that is not "none" or 0 will be "checked," so 1 would be "checked."

Comment: sorry, i put it wrong. When I input 0 or none into Cells (1,"A"), it still display "checked".

Comment: Instead of "Or" put "And."

Comment: As jbarker2160 has stated, the logic is wrong. Since `Cells(1, "A")` cannot be both  *not none OR not 0* at the same time, the statement will always be true. Changing `OR` to `And` should satisfy the logic.

Comment: The code will break if the content of the cell is, for example, the string `"test "`, because the `If` evaluate the second condition and you cannot compare `"test"` with `0` (type mismatch).

Comment: @CST-Link, did you test that theory?  Because you are wrong.  If the condition failed for the case you describe it would fail for all conditions since one condition is a string and the other is an integer, but it actually works for all conditions and also the condition that you describe.

Comment: @jbarker2160 Yes, apparently I am wrong (I just tested). But then, why? because if you write in the *Immediate* window something  like `?"test" <> 0` you'll get a type mismatch. However, is not like I'm asking you to answer that; I'll figure it out in the end... thanks for the reply.

Comment: @CST-Link, because in the context of an if statement, most implicit conversion failures return false and don't raise a RTE.  That's why you can say `If CInt("Test") Then` and it doesn't raise any error flags.

Comment: @jbarker2160 I tested your suggestion, and it raises exceptions (at least for VBA 7.0) from within `If` condition, so it couldn't be it. My guess is that some implicit conversion mechanism that I didn't know is executed (the `Range` returned by the `Cell` call gets converted to a `Variant` holding its `.Value`, and maybe is possible that `Variant`s can be compared to whatever), but I need to check. Again, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

A cell is referenced by a row and column or address. So use

`Cells(1,1)`

or

`Cells("A1")`

Comment: but even when I corrected this one, the cells (2,"A") always display checked even when i input 1 in cells (1,"A") and run the program. Is there's something wrong with my statement?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Sub Macro1()

        If Cells(1, 1) <> "none" Or Cells(1, 1) <> 0 Then
            Cells(1, 2) = "checked"
        Else
            Cells(1, 2) = "Not checked"
        End If

End Sub
```

Or you this:

```
Sub Macro2()

        If Range("A1") <> "none" Or Range("A1") <> 0 Then
            Range("B1") = "checked"
        Else
            Range("B1") = "Not checked"
        End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful to:

0) *respect the language's syntax/semantics:* is kind of obvious for a human, but what would mean `A` for VBA?

1) *be sure what cell values are you accessing:* i.e. which worksheet those cells belong to;

2) *ynot compare apples with oranges:* if something is a string, comparing it with an integer value gives you type mismatch errors. You need to be sure before comparing what type are you comparing.

3) *follow the rules of Boolean logic, not the the ones common language logic:* to say that something shouldn't be "none" or 0.0 doesn't translate logically into your `If` condition.

So, this is a proposal for a more robust macro:

```
Public Sub Macro1()
        Dim in_value  As Variant
        Dim out_value As String

        ' Adjust the name of the worksheet to your needs'
        With Worksheets("Sheet1")
                ' Read data '
                in_value = .Range("A1").Value

                ' Check what type '
                Select Case TypeName(in_value)
                Case "Empty"
                        Let out_value = "Not checked"

                Case "String"
                        If LCase(in_value) <> "none" Then
                                Let out_value = "checked"
                        Else
                                Let out_value = "Not checked"
                        End If

                Case "Integer", "Long", "Single", "Double"
                        If in_value <> 0 Then
                                Let out_value = "checked"
                        Else
                                Let out_value = "Not checked"
                        End If

                Case Else
                        Let out_value = "checked"
                End Select

                ' Write data '
                Let .Range("A2").Value = out_value
        End With
End Sub
```